# How to iterate through json elements using for in Python

Tags: python, json

This code works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request, json

url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22DKKNOK%2CEURNOK%2CGBPNOK%2CISKNOK%2CNOKNOK%2CPLNNOK%2CSEKNOK%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')

data = json.loads(url.read().decode(url.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')))

print(data['query']['results']['rate'][:])
```

It prints out all the 7 element of `data['query']['results']['rate']` in conjunction.

So I'm thinking this code should also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request, json

url = urllib.request.urlopen('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22DKKNOK%2CEURNOK%2CGBPNOK%2CISKNOK%2CNOKNOK%2CPLNNOK%2CSEKNOK%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')

data = json.loads(url.read().decode(url.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')))

for d in data['query']['results']['rate'][:]
    print(d)
```

Using `for` to loop and print out each of the elements in `data['query']['results']['rate']`.

However this does not work and gives an error.

How can I iterate through json elements in Python?

Comment: It would help if you could actually include the error (which is probably about the missing semicolon at the end of the for statement).

Comment: Please read error messages.  They are shown because they contain valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `[:]` to just iterate over the data:

```
for d in data['query']['results']['rate']:
    print(d)
```

.. should work. You're missing the `:`.

You can also use the `.json()` method directly on the response from requests to decode the JSON into a python structure.

Comment: Thanks. It was a simple. I just started with Python today and it shows :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
for d in data['query']['results']['rate']：
    print(d)
```

instead of

```
for d in data['query']['results']['rate'][:]
    print(d)                       #here    ^ missed :
```